# Python variables changing when they shouldn't

Tags: python-3.x

The code that I am working on is changing my temporary variables, and I can't figure out how to stop it. Essentially, this is the problem:

```
def example(array):
    temp = array
    for i in range whatever:
        #change array
```

I need to change array, but keep temp the same.

Comment: You usually only need the `copy` module if you need a *generic* copying function to copy objects independent of their type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line

```
temp = array
```

does not copy the contents of `array` – it simply binds another name to the same object.  How to actually copy an object depends on the type of the object.  For a NumPy array, you can do

```
temp = array.copy()
```

For a Python list, you can use the above line starting from Python 3.3; in eariler version, you can use

```
temp = array[:]
```

There are also the generic copying functions `copy()` and `deepcopy()` in the module `copy`.

Comment: I tried both of these options, and neither seems to work.  temp continues to change.

Comment: Nevermind. I'm just an idiot and skipped over the 'deepcopy()' suggestion.  It worked perfectly.  A million, billion thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`temp = array` only indicates that `temp` is another name for the contents of the `array` variable.

In general, if you want a copy, you can use the `copy` module and do:

```
import copy

temp = copy.copy(arr)  # or copy.deepcopy(arr), depending on the situation
```